# Render a Table the “wrong” way: transpose Columns and Rows

Tags: php

I found this code on here but I don't understand what the $n refers to. 
I tried it but it gives me data on a one line.

```
$data = array('name' => array(), 'birth' => array(), 'movie' => array());
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc(...)) {
$data['name'][] = $r['name'];
...
}

echo '<th>Name</th>';
foreach($data['name'] as $n) {
printf('<td>%s</td>', htmlspecialchars($n));
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: **"I found this code on here but I don't understand what the $n refers to"**

$data['name'] is an array, which seems to be filled from your database query.

In

```
foreach($data['name'] as $n) {
```

it is just looping through the array of names, on each iteration $n is assigned the value of the element in the array of names for that iteration

For your second question **"I tried it but it gives me data on a one line."**

that is correct.

```
printf('<td>%s</td>', htmlspecialchars($n));
```

the <td>s in this line prints out table cells. If you want rows, you need to use <tr> as well